# PostgreSQL query that deletes all results that have two repeated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cannot figure out a query to this, everything I find is immediately not doable thanks to the "group by" aspect of this.

```
ID   |    Username   | Age | arbitrary
1    |      bob      | 10  | 34
2    |      bob      | 10  | 54
3    |     alice     | 10  | 123
```

Where IDs 1 and 2 would both get deleted and have alice untouched. I've managed to create a web app that has a problem like this and would like to apply a unique(username, age) to patch it, but due to duplicates I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM thetable dd
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM thetable xx
    WHERE xx.username = dd.username
    AND xx.age = dd.age
    AND xx.id <> dd.id   -- if you want to delete ALL duplicates
    -- AND xx.id < dd.id -- if you want to keep only ONE of the duplicates
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around the "group by" aspect you can use a window function:

```
with duplicates as (
   select id, 
          count(*) over (partition by username, age) as dup_count
   from the_table
)
select *
from duplicates
where dup_count > 1;
```

More about window functions in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

This can be combined with a `delete` statement:

```
with duplicates as (
   select id, 
          count(*) over (partition by username, age) as dup_count
   from the_table
)
delete from the_table
where id in (select id 
             from duplicates 
             where dup_count > 1);
```

The above uses a data modifying CTE. More details about that can be found in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b0e3/1

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE username IN (SELECT username
              FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY username), username
                       FROM tablename) x 
             WHERE x.row_number > 1);


        ------RESULT------

 ID   |    Username   | Age | arbitrary
 -----+---------------+-----+----------
 3    |     alice     | 10  |   123
```

Comment: This would delete duplicate usernames only, not a combo of the age column. My bad about not being too clear about that.